# Search records in database for those that match what a user enters

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a function that searches records in my database for the object of those that match the SearchCriteria. The functions parameters look like so:

`RetrieveObject(SearchCriteria) As String (SearchCritera is a string aswell)`

Right now for testing purposes I am using a console app that asks the user to search by first name.

`Console.Writeline("Search by first name: ")
 Dim firstName = Console.Readline()`

I then use my function: `RetrieveObject(firstName)`

I want my function to show all the values (lastname, titlename, state, zip) for that particular person that was passed to the `RetrieveObject` function.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to understand how I'm going to match what the user enters with the value in the database.

If anyone could just put me in the right direction to help me understand how to accomplish this, I'd be so grateful!

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Function RetrieveObject(SearchCriteria As String) As String

    Dim cn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(myCon)

    Dim myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Applicant WHERE [strFirstName] LIKE '%son'"

    Using com As New OdbcCommand(myQuery)

        cn.Open()
        com.Connection = cn
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        com.CommandText = myQuery
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strFirstName", SearchCriteria)

        Try
            com.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Using

    Return SearchCriteria

End Function
```

Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that strFirstName is not a field of the table Applicant. What is the real name of the column that contains the FirstNames searched

Comment: strFirstName is the name of a field in the Applicant table. Also, the firstName variable used to store the user input from the console is actually Public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a WHERE condition you need to provide (at the most basic level) three informations to the database engine. The first bit is the column name that you want to search for, the second piece is the operator that you want to use for matching records, and finally the value to search for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FieldName = 'AStringValue'
```

Of course we could have a lot of variations with operators and field datatype but this answer is limited to your actual situation.

It is important to note that your query could return more than one record (in particular if you add wildcards operators as LIKE, so you cannot simply return a single value with this query, but instead you return a DataTable where you can loop over the Rows collection to see all the records returned by the query

So your code should be changed to

```
Private Function RetrieveObject(SearchCriteria As String) As DataTable
    Dim myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Applicant WHERE [strFirstName] LIKE ?"
    Try
        Using cn = New OdbcConnection(myCon)
        Using da = new OdbcDataAdapter(myQuery, cn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = SearchCriteria
            Dim dt = new DataTable()
            da.Fill(dt)
            return dt
         End Using
         End Using
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
         return Nothing
     End Try
End Function
```

Now you could call this method with something like

```
Dim table = RetrieveObject("John%")
if table IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each row in table.Rows
       Console.WriteLine(row["strFirstName"].ToString())
    Next
End If
```

If you really need to return a json string with all the FirstName matched then you could add this to the last lines of the code above

```
.....
da.Fill(dt)
Dim names = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("strFirstName")).ToArray()
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(names);
return output;
```

And of course change again the return value to be a string.

Comment: Steve, this all looks awesome! First thing I noticed those was that the function returns a DataTable. I guess I failed to clarify that it needs to return a 'String'. I will fool around with this code though! :) Again, thank you!! Will let you know how I make out.

Comment: You cant return a collection of records as string - not in any meaningful way at any rate

Comment: I'm sorry I need to clarify it even more! Lol. I need to return a JSON string which contains an array of objects that will match the criteria. I will get into that later though if I need more help.

Comment: @Steve, I don't have a field name searchCriteria.

Comment: @TimmyHoHoo It doesnt matter what the *final* form is supposed to be - the first step is to get those records.  The *next* step is to serialize them.

Comment: @Plutonix, Okay, but I'm just saying I don't have a searchCriteria field in my database. I have a strFirstName field. So I guess I just don't understand the part where he puts .Parameters.Add("@searchCriteria",..........)

Comment: `@SearchCriteria` is the name of the parameter, but I guess that Odbc cannot handle Named parameters. If this is the case then you need to replace the `@SearchCriteria` string with a single question mark (?)

Comment: Okay, will try this out. Thanks again.

Comment: The obvious question is why are you using ODBC - what is the database?

Comment: Damn... obviously I should be using SqlConnection.

Comment: And do you have a reason to use Odbc with Sql Server? A lot better choice is to use the classes in the SqlClient namespace

Comment: No reason, I was using an Access database before, but I switched over to a SQL database. So, now that I have it changed from Odbc to Sql should I try the code when you DID NOT have the ? in the query and in the .Add( I believe you had @searchCriteria.

Comment: Yes the SqlClient classes supports Named Parameters so you could add back again the @SearchCriteria string and name in the parameters collection (Check the history)

Comment: @Steve, What is this JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

Comment: @Steve - Thanks so much for your help! Very much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Steve is there another way of accomplishing this without using the newtonsoft namespace?

Comment: Dim output As String = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(names)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass your search criteria into function which returns `dataset` as shown below , one more thing ,you can use the function in textbox `textchange` event in forms

Also while search include `LIKE` as `LIKE '%" & @strFirstName & "%'` which can help you narrow search results if needed

```
Public Function Search(ByVal Criteria As String) As DataSet
        Try
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            stQuery="SELECT * FROM Applicant WHERE [strFirstName] 
                     LIKE '%" & @strFirstName & "%'"
                Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(stQuery, sqlCon)
                Dim sqlAda As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                sqlCmd .Parameters.AddWithValue("@strFirstName", Criteria )
                sqlAda.Fill(ds)
            End Using
            Return ds
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Function
```